# Node-Webkit Window Context

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-webkit

I've just started using node-webkit and came up with a serous question.

I want to wrap a website that has been build on external domain in my nw app.
Therefore on my app's index.html file load, I'm redirecting to my website:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
```

The problem is that after the redirect, the Window context looses all of his nw capabilities. For example, access to:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
```

How I can overcome this obstacle (Iframe is an idea, but his Window context is different than my websites Window context)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `node-remote` + url in `package.json`.
For reference, [Node-Webkit (nw.js) manifest wiki](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Manifest-format#node-remote)